# java.io.IOException: Read-only file system, when testing on android virtual device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

While I'm testing on android virtual device on android studio, I get `java.io.IOException: Read-only file system` error when I try to write file.
I guess this is because the program is trying to create/write the file onto the virtual android device that is on the test file, but having said that, I have no idea how can I save a file to "local" file system, like "C:_tmp_output.json".

I also added uses-permission `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` lines but didn't work as I could expect. Would anyone help me out for the issue? Thank you.

```
    File test = new File("C:\\_tmp\\_output.json");
    test.createNewFile() ;
    FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C:\\_tmp\\_output.json");
    file.write(String.valueOf("foobar"));
```

Comment: C: is a partition on a windows pc. It does not exist on an Android device or emulator.

Comment: okay sorry about that @blackapps

Comment: @blackapps I want to save a file locally anyway, while that testing. I understand that, but are there no way to save a file to windows file system? Or I don't mind it would be the android device, either way, I get the permission error so cannot save a file to anywhere.

Comment: Then choose a possible path like getFilesDir() or getExternalFilesDir(null).

Comment: getFilesDir() or getExternalFilesDir(null), okay, I'll take a look how to use them. thanks for the advice

Comment: I don't know... I tried and googled but `Cannot resolve method 'getExternalFilesDir'` it says. why just writing to a file could be this difficult and complicated.

Comment: @blackapps do you have examples for the methods? I'm working on these stuff for hours but no idea how can I implement.

Comment: Take an activity and call that function. You called it at the wrong place. A place without a context.

Comment: still I don't get it about windows-level file saving, but I could save a file onto the android machine without error using `getApplicationContext()` and copy the content to local file system with `adb shell cat /path/to/file.json > /path/to/file.json`. I'll learn about android and java one by one, so far I'm okay with this. thanks @blackapps